# Product image not displaying in wishlist page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, wishlist

I have created one attribute called imageurl for importing product image url. Product images displaying all the pages except minicart and wishlist page. For displaying product image in wishlist page I made some changes in 
**wishlist/item/column/image.phtml** file. 
But its not working.

`<img src="<?php echo $_product->getData('imageurl') ?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit `/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/wishlist/item/column/image.phtml` and use below code to get an `ImageUrl` :

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId())->getImageurl(); ?>" />
```

Comment: thank you... now its working...          `<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($product->getId())->getData(imageurl'); ?>" />`